# Image database for processing in MATLAB

Tags: mysql, sql, matlab, image-processing

I want to create an image database which can be entirely accessed via MATLAB. I don't want to create any folder and save the image name in a database as it is not exactly suitable for my application. Can i go for it using SQL? if yes then please explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want yo store images in datanase you can use `BLOB` datatype.

A `BLOB` is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data. The four BLOB types TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB and LONGBLOB differ only in the maximum length of the values they can hold.

The article here explains how it works:

http://www.weberdev.com/ViewArticle/Saving-Images-in-MySQL

Comment: How does the query performance compare to accessing an image directly from the hard drive?

Comment: If it is images - the database. The performance can be as good as file system especially if you retrieve the file together with the file name and you preserve data integrity which is much more important than performance at least for business apps and regular websites

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.9](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=404192). Create an ODBC datasource using ODBC Administrator, then in matlab type querybuilder. I'm assuming you followed the link in @Teez post about saving images in MySQL. If so create the query to retrieve the image in MATLAB visual query builder then hit the execute button. This should bring the required images into MATLABS workspace. You should be able to do the same thing in a UDF and with parameters linked to the where clause. Hope this helped.

Comment: obviously you will need MySQL installed on the target system